# A simple pic car

Tags: pic

I have very little knowledge.

I want to make a car.

I'm going to use pic16f84 and I'm not going use any sensors. I just need the car to go forward.

But what materials should I buy?

Can I do it with just a servo motor and the pic?
Which pcb can I use?

Comment: Why a PIC? Just a battery a DC motor and an on/off switch. :)

Comment: @kenny, no need to deter someone from learning microcontrollers.

Comment: @Kortuk, that's not my intention. But just trying to say how simple a DC motor is.

Comment: @kenny, can we use that for a BLDC motor?

Comment: @Kortuk, I never tried but I'm pretty sure you can get it to move. Typically those are used with a higher end controller to drive. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_dc_motor

Comment: @kenny, I do not think they work with just a switch, they need a higher end controller because you need feedback to control it, it is not a simple on/off. I think learning motor control algorithms is worth it, even if right now he has a simple brushed motor.

Comment: Maybe he wants to control the speed of the motor? He didn't inform us about the motor type either :) It's interesting how questions like this make answerers fight :)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution would be DC motors, a switch of some sort to turn the motors on ( Transistor or FET) power and a whatever the PIC needs to run.

Parts needed

- dc motor
- diode (1n4xxx) for each motor
- NPN channel FET or transistor, depends on motor
- PIC and whatever it needs
- few resistors, pull up and current limiting
- PCB - any proto or perf board of your choice
- power of some sort ( battery, solar panel, wall wort)

as for the servo idea, it would work if you have a continuous rotation servo.

Comment: A car that's powered from a wall wart would have a somewhat limited range...

Comment: Personally, I prefer to use an H-bridge instead of bare transistors (and diodes), but it's functionally the same.

Comment: if they have an H-bridge chip cool but if you have a whole bunch of transistors then why not make your own :)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, to make the car go forward you could just use a battery and motors.

As for the 'forward' aspect: the most obvious way to make a car is to use two geared motors to driver a left and right wheel, but this will result in a car that moves approximately forwared, plus or minus maybe 90 degrees :) Powering the two wheels from one motor and using a servo motor to steer the other (front?) wheels is more liklely to result in a straight line movement.

As for the PIC, please consider a less stone-age one. Just a few suggestions: 16F886, 18F2520. Both are MUCH more powerfull, 28 pin, and cost less than a 16F84. (Does anyone still sell those chips??)

From your question I think you should consider something simpler than a uC-controller car, maybe google for 'beam robot'? The term beam is used for robotic vehicle like thingies that use very very simple hardware, and often solar panel power.